# What did I lose when I upgraded?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, windows-7-x64, projects-and-solutions

I upgraded my work box from Vista64 to Win7-64 by doing a format and reinstall.
I kept backups of the project done in MS Visual Studio 2008 (Team).
But now it won't compile. I am getting errors generated on lines in the MS created header files like "'_In_' not defined" etc.
I know it is because I *lost* some compiler setting/directive. I was *sure* that the compiler settings would be in the project file; now I see that things like the include file directories, LIB files, etc. are not.
[FYI: The project is a VB.NET GUI with VC++ DLL talking to a PIC24 micro over USB.]

How do I most efficiently get my project back on the road to execution?

Comment: Do you have the PIC24 drivers and SDK installed ?